# Resize 9 patch image with respect to content

Tags: android, nine-patch

I need my 9-patch image to wrap the content. If there is a little text, it should be really small to wrap that text. And if there is an image insetead of text it should wrap it too.
Here is my 9-patch png:

[image: 9-patch]

But here it what it looks like with content:

[image: Message]

This is the code in xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/message_text_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/other_user_layout"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/user_layout"
    android:layout_below="@id/message_date"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm setting the background to this relative layout programmatically.
How can I make this message layout to exactly fit the content and not stretching all over the screen.

Comment: Did you know? you can save on the RealtiveLayout and the ImageView, and have a single TextView. So, to increase performances.

Comment: @DerGolem Not really, how can I do it? I heard that I can put an image to the side of the textview but I don't know how to implement it here.

Comment: in xml: use `drawableRight="@drawable/balloon"`. In Java, use `setCompoundRwawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`. You can set 4 drawables at once. The RelativeLayout container is then useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in lines:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/other_user_layout"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/user_layout"
```

I am setting one of this programmatically depending on the message author.

Answer (score 0):

try using only textview

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
    android:layout_background="@drawable/img"/>
```

instead of

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/message_text_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/other_user_layout"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/user_layout"
android:layout_below="@id/message_date"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/message_picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```